# Android Default Shared Preferences File Readable By Multiple Apps?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How can I have a shared preferences file that can be read by more than one app.  In particular by an admin app and the app it is administrating?

Comment: where would I put such a file and with what privilges?

Comment: there is also default shared preferences via the PreferencesManager .....

Comment: @Androider: This is *so* not a good idea. Bear in mind that it will be readable by any application, not just your "admin app and the app it is administrating". Please write a real API (`ContentProvider`, remote service w/ AIDL, or whatever) and implement real security to enable data sharing between these two apps and only these two apps.

Comment: whats the best way to do this?  Not really inclinded to use AIDL, so how would a ContentProvider allow such settings to flow from admin write to application (read)?  whats the common way?

Comment: any thoughts on a shared SQLite DB?  Also a bad idea?

Comment: you skipped right by  CommonsWare's ContentProvider option, only to go on to wonder about a "shared SQLite DB"?  AFAIK an Android ContentProvider equals a "shared SQLite DB".   Slow down and pay attention to commonsware, he knows his stuff.

Comment: whats important is that we establish a good way to communicate between apps.  I mean its not real clear to me if there is a good way to share information across apps.  There are these modes which are allowed but not recommended and the spec speaks against them.  It looks to me like the answer is there is no clean way to do this that is android way, and some ways are worse then others but none are good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getSharedPreferences()` with `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` (assuming that both apps are supposed to be able to write to it)? One of the apps will have to create a context using the package of the other app.

Comment: How would the app create a context using the package of the other app?

Comment: `Context.createPackageContext()`.

Comment: Please please please please please please please please please please please please do *NOT* use `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. "WORLD" means "all apps on the device", meaning you are just begging to be hacked. Even `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I would agree that sharing a file like this is not such a good idea the basic need to to be able to set the preferences and parameters of an app from outside the app itself. It would be good if there were a common way to do this.

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question as far as how it could be done so, but I think it is not the best way.  So lets talk about the best way?